# Classic ASP + Javascript - trying to avoid sessions

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, session-variables

please be patient with my poor english...

I started working on a classic ASP application developed by others. Lots and lots of pages, not well organized : the typical situation you have to face when you come to an existing website.

We now have a big problem : lots of log outs due to losts of session variables.
So I am trying to write a script to avoid sessions.

Luckily, there is a common page which is included in every page of the application.
My first step will be the transition from now to the future : the application is already in production so first I will leave the session variables as is and add my script at the top of the included page.

The ASP script defines the names of the session variables which are critical, retrieves their values on the request.form collection and add the values in the session.contents collection.
Then the Javascript script create hidden inputs containing the values on the page load, in order to post them to the next page (it will fill existing forms and create new form when the user clicks on a link). To be sure there are no conflicts, a specific word is used for every name : name="specific_myName"

Please can somebody tell me if this is a good approach ? If so the script will have to be improved...
Thank you

Below the script :

```vb
<%
Class ConnexionState
    ' #### Connexion
    Private m_dict
    Private m_keys 
    Private m_Javascript
    Private m_specific
    Private m_deconnection
    Public Property Get GetDict()
        Set GetDict = m_dict
    End Property
    Public Sub Class_Initialize()
        ' Test if connexion is allowed
        TestConnexion
        ' Initilize datas + retrieve "session" variables
        m_specific = "Connexion_"
        Init
    End Sub
    Public Sub Class_Terminate()
        Set m_dict = Nothing
    End Sub
    Private Sub TestConnexion()
        ' One test may be : do we come from a page of the same application ?
        If Instr(1,Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER"),Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"),1) = 0 And Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") <> "" Then
            EndConnexion
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Validate(key_)
        ' Test if variables are well formatted : for example check if we get an integer if we expect an integer
        m_deconnection = false
        On Error Resume Next
        Select Case key_
            ' Expecting an integer
            'Case "key_integer_1","key_integer_2"...
            '    m_dict(key_) = CStr(CInt(m_dict(key_)))
                ' Expecting a string which lenght is 6
            Case "key_string_1"
                If m_dict(key_) <> "" And Len(m_dict(key_)) <> 6 Then m_deconnection = True
            Case Else
                ' Avoid values which length is too high 
                If Len(m_dict(key_)) > 25 Then m_deconnection = True
        End Select
        ' Avoid ' character
        If InStr(m_dict(key_),"'") > 0 Then m_deconnection = True
        ' If we got an error or one variable is not well formatted
        If Err.Number > 0 Or m_deconnection = True Then
            EndConnexion
        End If
        On Error Goto 0
    End Sub
    Private Sub EndConnexion()
        response.end
    End Sub
    Private Sub Init()
        Dim i
        Set m_dict = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' Names of the "session" variables
        ' m_keys = Array(    names_ )
        ' We do some stuff on each key
        For Each i In m_keys
            SetValue(i)
        Next
    End Sub
    Public Function ToString()
        ' Pass a string (will be used in the javascript below)
        Dim i
        ToString = ""
        For Each i In m_dict.keys
            If InStr(m_dict(i),"=") = 0 then
                ToString = ToString & i & "=" & m_dict(i) & "&"
            End if
        Next
        ToString = ToString & "specific=" & m_specific & "&"
        If ToString <> "" then
            ToString = Left(ToString,Len(ToString)-1)
        End If
    End Function
    Private Sub SetValue(key_)
        ' Retrieve values from request.form collection
        m_dict(key_) = request.form(m_specific & key_)
        ' If not in request.form, we try in session.contents
        If m_dict(key_) = "" Then
            m_dict(key_) = Session(key_)
        End If
        ' Test if value is well formatted
        Validate(key_)
        ' Update session
        session(key_) = m_dict(key_)
    End Sub
End Class

Dim Connexion
Set Connexion = New ConnexionState
%>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var Connexion = (function() {
            function init(args_) {
                // Translate "session" variables from a string passed in argument to object properties
                var params_ = args_[0],
                    p;
                for (var i in params_.split("&")) {
                    try {
                        this[params_.split("&")[i].split("=")[0]] = params_.split("&")[i].split("=")[1];    
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        // do something
                    }        
                }
                // Load click event listener
                load.call(this);
                return;
            } 
            function load() {
                // What happens on page load
                var that = this;
                window.onload = function() {
                    document.onclick = function(event) {
                        event = event || window.event;
                        var t = event.target || event.srcElement,
                            p,
                            input;
                        // Click on a link -> we create a form and post values to the next page
                        if (t.tagName && t.tagName.toLowerCase() === "a" && (typeof t.onclick).toLowerCase() !== "function") {
                            send.call(that,t.href,t.target);
                            return false;    
                        } 
                        // Click on an input button -> we get the form containing th input and add hidden inputs containing connexion parameters inside it
                        if (t.tagName && t.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
                            p = t;
                            while (p != null) {
                                if (p.tagName && p.tagName.toLowerCase() === "form") {
                                    appendInputs.call(that,p,true);
                                    return;
                                }
                                p = p.parentNode;
                            }
                            return;    
                        } 
                        return;
                    }        
                    // If there is any form inside th page we add hidden inputs containing connexion parameters inside it
                    var formsInDocument = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
                    for (var i=0;i<formsInDocument.length ;i++ ) {
                        appendInputs.call(that,formsInDocument[i],true);
                    }                    
                }
            }
            function send(action_,target_) {
                // Create a form and post connexion parameters to the next page
                var form = document.createElement("form"),
                    body;
                form.name = "Connexion";
                if (action_) { form.action = action_; }
                if (target_) { form.target = target_; }
                form.method = "post";
                // Add hidden inputs containing connexion parameters
                appendInputs.call(this,form);
                // If body tag does not exist we create it
                if (!document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]) {
                    body = document.createElement("body");
                    document.documentElement.appendChild(body);
                    body.appendChild(form);
                } else {
                    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(form);
                }
                form.submit();
                return false;
            }
            function appendInputs(form_,testExists_) {
                // Add hidden inputs containing connexion parameters inside a form
                var input;
                for (var p in this) {
                    if (this.hasOwnProperty(p) && (typeof this[p]).toLowerCase() != "function" && p.toLowerCase() != "specific") {
                        if ((testExists_ && !document.getElementsByName(p)[0]) || !testExists_) {
                            input = document.createElement("input");
                            input.type = "hidden";
                            input.name = this["specific"] + p;
                            input.value = this[p];
                            form_.appendChild(input);
                            console.log("    " + input.name + " - " + input.value);
                        }
                    }        
                }
                return;
            }
            return {
                init: init
            }
        })();
        Connexion.init(arguments);
    })("<%=Connexion.ToString()%>");
</script>
```

Comment: Any reason your `ConnexionState` class has a missing variable name (just says `Private`) on line 7? Is it a typo perhaps?

Comment: thank you for replying it was an error copying and pasting the code, you can ignore it.

Comment: I edited the code after Lankymart's comment.

Comment: What's wrong with letting an inactive user have their session expire?  With this approach they will always be logged in which could be a security risk if they use  a machine in a public area.  your approach requires the user to explicitly log off.

Comment: Next step would we not using session variables anymore and adding <%@ ENABLESESSIONSTATE=False %> in pages, next step disabling session state in IIS